# internal links to jupyter notebook section in plotly figure

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I am using Jupyter and Plotly to produce a set of plots, text and indicators that I then export in HTML, to produce a sort of "dashboard" that people can navigate to get data.

To produce an interactive table of contents, where users can click and go directly to the desired section, so far I followed this nice tutorial
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_ipython_internal_links.html

The problem is that this only works with Markdown, and I would like to have instead something more adaptable and graphically pleasant.

I thought I could get away with producing a plotly multiplot with big clickable buttons to the different sections. Something like

```
---------------     ---------------     ---------------
¦  Section 1  ¦     ¦  Section 2  ¦     ¦  Section 3  ¦ 
---------------     ---------------     ---------------
```

So far, I'm able to get what I want using Markdowns. Internal link destinations in the notebook are defined as

```
from IPython.display import Markdown as md

#destination of an internal link
md(f"""<a id='Section_1'></a>""")
```

And they can be called as

```
md(f"""<a href='#Section_1'> Go to Section 1 </a>""")
```

Crucially, this also works when I export the notebook in html, which is the file I eventually send around.

However, when I try to put a link in a Plotly figure (via text annotation, for example) the situation is different. If I do something like that:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))
fig.add_annotation(x=6, y=10,
            text="<a href='#Section_1'>Go to Section 1</a>",
            showarrow=False,
            yshift=10)
fig.show()
```

two things can happen:

- In the Jupyter notebook, if I click on the link, instead of jumping to the right session, it opens a new tab with a copy of the notebook, and then jumps to the session.
- When I export it in html, the link is simply not transfered and - although clickable - nothing happens. Weirdly, if instead of referring to an internal section of the document I try an external link, say "www.wikipedia.com", it works just fine.

The code I use to export the notebook in html is

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.io as pio

pyo.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
pio.renderers.default = "notebook"

from nbconvert import HTMLExporter
from nbconvert import PDFExporter
from nbconvert.writers import FilesWriter


nb_name = 'My notebook'

exporter = HTMLExporter(exclude_input=True,  exclude_output_prompt = True)

(body, resources) = exporter.from_filename(f'{nb_name}.ipynb')

write_file = FilesWriter()

write_file.write(
    output=body,
    resources=resources,
    notebook_name=nb_name
)
```

Maybe the problem is how the link is exported in the html conversion, maybe it's with Plotly itself. Any idea or alternative I could use to get the result I want?

Comment: i believe the default behavior of hyperlinks in plotly text annotations will open in a new window (for example, when you use an external link, am i correct in assuming it opens in a new window?). if that's the case, then that might explain why when you use an anchor and link to that within your plotly figure, it still opens in a new window. can you include an example of the text annotations you are trying to use inside your figure to link to an anchor within your page?

Comment: Thanks Derek. I think you are right, but it is a bit weirder than that. When I link an external website it opens a new tab and redirects to that website. When I try linkin an anchor within my page, with something like
<a href='#Section_1'>
it does not work at all.

Comment: Derek, any idea on how I could solve my issue? It seems to be due to how plotly links are transferred (or not, in this case) in html. Any tweak on the PDFExporter settings that might help me? Or perhaps a completely different approach would give me what I ask for: a clickable set of buttons with links to anchors in my html file?